# How to open pdf file in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: pdf, windows-phone-8

I have some pdf files inside (the project files) my app and I wanted how to open in Adobe Reader or the other, but I don't know how.

In iOS is more easy and in Android I know how, but I don't know how in WP8.

I'm new in Windows Phone 8 :/

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the [`LaunchFileAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh701471.aspx) method of `Launcher` class. Example:

```cs
// Access the file.
StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("file.pdf");

// Launch the pdf file.
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);
```

You will find more info here:

[Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: With this code the app show this error: The thread 0xf68 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Comment: The file.pdf is in the same level that App.xml

Comment: but, What is my file's path?

Comment: I see, ERROR: "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: To execute"StorageFile pdfFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("file.pdf");", try catch capture an exception that says "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, it works fine for me. Maybe you should ask a new question with this specific problem, ans see if someone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Save the downloaded file to the isolated storage...

```
async void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
    await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile("your-file.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Open and display the pdf file from the isolated storage..

```
// Access the file.
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync("your-file.pdf");

// Launch the pdf file.
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async void launchPDF()
{
 string fileURL = @"Assets\file.pdf";
 StorageFile pdfFile = await 
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileURL);
 if (pdfFile != null)
 {
   IAsyncOperation<bool> success = 
           Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdfFile);

   if (await success)
   {
     // File launched
   }
   else
   {
     // File launch failed
   }
 }
 else
 {

 }
}
```

Make sure pdf file build action is content