# Associate a file to a particular app in windows phone 8

Tags: android, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a file manager for windows phone 8. In android we can use mime type to associate files to its corresponding apps I would like to achieve the same in windows phone 8 how do I do it?

Comment: Simple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does not work the same as Android as far as file association goes.  The OS just kind of "handles" all of this for you.  The extent of what you can do (as far as I know) is try open a file by using LaunchFileAsync().  If the system has an app that has registered for that file association, the user will be presented with a screen allowing them to choose which app to open the file with.  If you pass in a file that no apps have an association for, the user will be presented with a screen offering to search the store for an app that can handle that file type.

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[More specifics on LaunchFileAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615504/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-windows-phone-8)