# Relative (or absolute) path for GetFileAsync()?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I see all these examples about launching a PDF file so I think it is trivial, e.g. [How to open pdf file in Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615504/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-windows-phone-8)

I uploaded the file into the Assets directory of my project and I tried:

```
string fil = @"Assets\myCopy.pdf";  
StorageFile theStorage = await GetFileAsync( fil );
```

And it keeps dying with `File.IOException.NotFound`.

Comment: Can you add the exact code you're using? `GetFileAsync` is not a free function, so presumably you are calling it from some object.

Comment: What is the build action of the PDF file? Set it as "Content" if it was "None".

Comment: I am not sure how this will help, but...the object calling GetFileAsync from a xaml page code-behind..

Comment: For some reason I cannot paste the code in here...

Comment: It looks like the "Build Action" change fixed this..it tried to install the Adobe PDF reader in the emulator...Thanks much

Comment: I got this to work on a platform with Adobe installed!