# WP8.1 write blob to file system

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

It is so simple what I want to do!! This works fine on Android (IOS I can use a Blob URL)

I have a local blob which is a pdf in this case. I want the user to be able to view the pdf. How can I achieve this?

I have tried using the file plugin (org.apache.cordova.file) to save to local storage and then use the fileopener2 plugin to open it. This approach works on Android. For WP8.1 it seems this approach will not work.

First issue is I can't even save the blob to local storage. The documentation for Windows Phone 8 for the file plugin is very very poor and googling brings up very little.

Second issue is the file plugin documentation does mark windows phone 8 as not supporting writing blobs. Why is this? I noticed in the code that the blob can be converted to a base64 encoded string, so I assume this means it must be possible to write a blob in wp8.1 where the base64 encoded string is converted back to a blob in the native part of the plugin.

In WP8.1 in the file plugin what file system URL do you use? None of the cordova.file.* properties are defined.

If someone can just show me how to write a text file to local storage which I can then open using the fileopener2 plugin I could then proceed from there.

I appreciate any help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can write blobs, but everything you want to persist can only be saved in the local-app-storage. so files are only accessible from the app, which have written the file.

to save an object serialize/convert it to a string and conduct something like this:

```
   Private Async Function WriteToFileAsync(content As String, folder As String, filename As String) As Task
    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content.ToCharArray())
    Dim local As StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
    Dim dataFolder = Await local.CreateFolderAsync(folder, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
    Dim file = Await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
    Using stream = Await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()
        stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length)
    End Using
End Function
```

to open an existing pdf-file, use `LaunchFileAsync(...)` ,  take a look at this page: [How to open pdf file in Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615504/how-to-open-pdf-file-in-windows-phone-8)

you can start other apps with Parameter but unfortunately apps cannot communicate directly among each other and the max length of the Parameter is not adapted for blobs.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @anion for his answer, which put me on the right track to find a solution to this.

What I found was that using the fileopener2 plugin, I couldn't save the file (using the standard file plugin) into one of the paths provided and then have fileopener2 find it again. The trick was to add a new method to fileopener2 (just for WP8) where I could pass in the file's contents. It would then save it to local storage (using code similar to @anion's answer) and then immediately launch it using code similar to it's existing "open" method.

In my case I've got the base64 string of the file before I pass it to the plugin, which I guess you have similar if you're starting with a blob.

In the fileopener2 plugin, go to src\wp8 and add this to the FileOpener2.cs:

```
        public async void saveAndOpen(string options)
    {

        string[] args = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options);
        string aliasCurrentCommandCallbackId = args[2];

        try
        {
            string base64 = args[0];

            byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("SpendControlTemp", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(args[1], CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                stream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            }


            // Launch the bug query file.
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), aliasCurrentCommandCallbackId);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.IO_EXCEPTION), aliasCurrentCommandCallbackId);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR), aliasCurrentCommandCallbackId);
        }
    }
```

Then, in the www folder, add this to plugins.FileOpener2.js, just before the bit that adds the "open" method:

```
FileOpener2.prototype.saveAndOpen = function (base64, fileName, callbackContext) {
callbackContext = callbackContext || {};
exec(callbackContext.success || null, callbackContext.error || null, 'FileOpener2', 'saveAndOpen', [base64, fileName]);
```

};

Then, in your cordova javascript, you can do something like this, only for WP8 though (you may be able to merge this in using the merges folders, so iOS and Android do it the "normal" way):

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.saveAndOpen(myBase64String, myFileName);
```

That got me up and running, hope it helps you!